# How do I configure which Cinnamon applets spawn on log-in?

Tags: taskbar, cinnamon, debian-stretch, applet, devuan

I use Devuan Ascii / Debian Stretch, with Cinnamon. Whenever I login, several applets which I have removed from the panel last time - appear again: Bluetooth, Accessibility, Clipboard manager thingy... where do I choose which of them actually appear? I tried "Applets" in "System Settings", but some of them didn't appear there at all (e.g. Bluetooth) and some were listed as not on the panel (e.g. Accessibility). What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

It's under Startup Applications (note - old screenshot, not from Devuan 2):

[image]